# WiFi on Linux Mint with old early 2008 MacBook

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, macintosh

I just installed Linux Mint 20.2 Uma on an early 2008 MacBook.

Everything works fine, except WiFi...

Basically WiFi networks are detected, no problem. But when it tries to connect to the Internet, I get "Requesting a wireless network address" for a minute, and it never goes any further (passwords are the right ones). I tried with 3 different networks to be sure it wasn't coming from that.

Wired connection works fine.

I tried installing and reinstalling drivers (Broadcom), proprietary and free... But I'm starting to think it might not be a driver-related issue.

If any of you have any ideas, would love to be able to make it work...

Comment: Could it be a security issue? I remember having issues with older computers and newer WIFI routers. Something like WPA and WPA2, I think. It's worth checking, I'd say. Or you try it with a USB WiFi dongle.

Comment: Do you still have MacOS installed? You could try from there and so rule out an incompatibility with the AP for example.

Comment: Nope, I totally deleted MacOS. But it worked before I uninstalled it (and on the same networks I'm trying to connect to now), so I don't think it's an incompatibility... The problem came up only with Linux. I guess if I can't make it work I'll use a USB dongle.

Comment: What also could help is a different live distro like openSUSE and see if that issue is the same for different linux distros.

Comment: Just tried with a dongle, that worked. I'll give it a go with openSUSE.